# How to get number of false in every column of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table say T_myTable it has 5 columns and all have some values either true or false.

```
--------------------------------
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
--------------------------------
true | false|false|true |false
false| true |false|false|false
true | false|false|true |false
false| false|false|true |false
```

### I want to get result as:-

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5
--------------------------------
2    | 3    |4     |1     |4
```

Where these numbers here are numbers of false.
Also true and false are **varchar**.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Col1 = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col1
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Col2 = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col2
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Col3 = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col3
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Col4 = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col4
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Col5 = 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Col5
FROM T_myTable
```

Comment: @user6102644 if col1..5 are Boolean columns then you can have small edition in this select query as comparing column values with direct `false` instead of comparing with string `'false'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE col1 WHEN 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE col2 WHEN 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE col3 WHEN 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE col4 WHEN 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    SUM(CASE col5 WHEN 'false' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM T_myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the most interesting way is to:

1. unpivot data to be able to filter data
2. pivot data again to get count of 'false'

Check this:

```
SELECT [col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5]
FROM (
    SELECT MyVal, ColName
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM T_myTable
        ) AS pvt
    UNPIVOT(MyVal FOR ColName IN ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5])) AS unpvt
    WHERE MyVAl = 'false'
    ) As DT
PIVOT (COUNT(MyVal) FOR ColName IN ([col1],[col2],[col3],[col4],[col5])) AS PT
```

Result:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
2       3       4       1       4
```